# $\cos^{2}(\phi)$ in the kinetic energy term of the Lagrangian is one?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm doing some homework in Classical Mechanics, and is about to write out the Lagrangian of a system. But, when I check the answer from my teacher, something is missing.

The kinetic energy I'm using is given by:

$$T =\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x_{m}}^{2},$$

where

$$\dot{x_{m}} = \dot{x}+L \cos(\phi)\dot{\phi}$$

Now, when I want to write out the entire Lagrangian I need to expand the squared $\dot{x_{m}}$, which in my calculations give me the following:

$$\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^{2}+2\dot{x}L \cos(\phi)\dot{\phi}+L^{2} \cos^{2}(\phi)\dot{\phi}^{2})$$

But apparently, according to the solution, the $\cos^{2}(\phi)$ term becomes $1$, and only $L^{2}\dot{\phi}^{2}$ is left.

So my question is: Why is that? I've been checking around, but nothing I find makes it one. I know that $\cos^{2}(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2\phi))$, but that doesn't seem to help me either.

Comment: You seem to be missing a potential energy term in your Lagrangian

Comment: Yup, but that is intentional, since it has nothing to do with why the $cos^{2}(\phi)$ equals one. It's just something I add in the end of the Lagrangian.

Comment: I'm not sure what the context is, but are you simply making a small angle approximation, $\cos \theta \approx 1 $?

Comment: What's the precise system you're considering?

Comment: That's what I thought, but then the other cos should disappear as well, shouldn't it?
The system is at page 301 (Problem 7.31) in this book: http://tberg.dk/books/Classical_Mechanics_(Taylor).pdf

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, the potential energy should have nothing to do with reducing the $cos^{2}(\phi)$, and the kinetic energy of the wagon is just $\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2$ anyways, so that shouldn't do anything either. So I only got the thing I wrote above, and from that, it seems that the $cos^{2}(\phi)$ becomes one somehow. Even if I check the result in the back of the book as well.

Comment: The problem is at page 301 of the pdf file, the actual page is 286 in the book.

Comment: That's a pretty big PDF. You should probably copy the problem text into the actual question so we can get some context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if I read the problem correctly then your kinetic energy is wrong. Your $\dot{x}_m$ is the $x$-component of the velocity of the ball, but you're missing the $y$-component and also the velocity of the cart, not to mention you're multiplying $\dot{x}_m^2$ by $m$ when you should be multiplying it by $M$.

The $\cos^2\phi$ goes away because the $y$-component of the ball's velocity has $\sin \phi$ in it, and as we all know $\cos^2 \phi + \sin ^2 \phi = 1$.

Comment: Yup. You are absolutely right. I have no idea why I didn't see, that I had to use the y-component as well. Sometimes it just take hours to find out :(
But thanks a lot, really helped.